# EF4.3 many to many table as entity

Tags: entity-framework, mapping, many-to-many

I have there entities two are normal the other is mapping between each other any time I put navigation mapping on I get invalid object name.
If I try and map  I get table already in schema.

```
EntityA EntityB        EntityC
Id      Id             EntityA has FK} PrimaryKey 
Name    description    EntityB has FK}
```

The mapping classes
I have taken all navigation on EntityB that caused my problems and entity after trying that

I tried this id in entity c but still got invalid table name. the name it was trying to create was dbo.BA where the  actual table is dbo.tblAB

```
 //entity.HasRequired(p => p.A).WithMany(p =>   p.C).HasForeignKey(p => p.EntityA);
 //entity.HasRequired(p => p.B).WithMany(p => p.C).HasForeignKey(p => p.EntityB)
```

I cannot use the .map because I need to use the  all three entities with in the DAL
Mapping classes
Entity C

```
entity.HasKey(t => new {t.EntityA, t.EntityB});
            entity.Property(qa => qa.EntityA).IsRequired();
            entity.Property(qa => qa.EntityB.).IsRequired();
            entity.toTable("tblC)
```

this was exiting table and because we need to delete these records we need to do through the entity.
Entity B and Entity A have ICollection Properties to Entity C  and mapping of

In Entity A mapping

```
entity.HasMany(g => g.C).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(p => p.EntityA).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

In entity B mapping

```
entity.HasMany(g => g.C).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(p => p.EntityB).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

In entity C mapping

```
entity.Property(t => t.EntityA).HasColumnName("EntityA");
            entity.Property(t => t.EntityB).HasColumnName("EntityB");
            entity.Map(c => c.ToTable("tblC")).HasKey(t => new { t.EntityA, t.EntityB });*
```

I was getting a multiplicity error but now I am getting Invalid column name 'EntityC_EntityA'. Invalid column name 'EntityC_EntityB'.

---

UPDATE
I have now fixed the schema with 
In EntityC

```
[Key, Column(Order = 0), ForeignKey("EntityA")]
[Key, Column(Order = 1), ForeignKey("EntityB"))
```

Navigaton properties

```
[ForeignKey("Id")]
public virtual EntityA EntityA { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("Id")]
public virtual EntityB EntityB { get; set; }
```

In the Entity A and b mapping

```
    entity.HasMany(g => g.Cs).WithRequired(p=>p.EntityA).HasForeignKey(p => p.EntityA).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
entity.HasMany(g => g.Cs).WithRequired(p=>p.EntityB).HasForeignKey(p => p.EntityB).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

---

The problem know that the query is trying to create the db.BA table.
The query I have tried is

```
ctx.EntityAs.Include(p => p.Cs.Select(pr => pr.EntityB))
        .Include(p => p.EntityBs.Select(pr => pr.Cs.Select(ps =>    ps.EntityA)))
```

Comment: It is not a duplicate because I need to keep the entity and not use the map function

Comment: how do I mark you as right, thank your help been trying for and a half to get this sorted

Comment: I have done it says now im getting enthough I have set the column names Invalid column name 'C_EntityA'. and C_EntityB

Comment: I am still struggling with this even though I have gone with the answer you suggested. Multiplicity is the problem now

Comment: This is a 1:1 mapping between A and C, and a 1:n mapping between B and C.

Comment: no its a 1:n A To C and B To C with A to B N:N @GertArnold

Comment: Then I don't understand `EntityA has FK} PrimaryKey` in EntityC.

Comment: It composite key that's why I put the brackets @Gert Arnold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to thank Gert Arnold for putting in the write direction. The answer for the schema is in the question
The Linq to solve the many is to include EntityC with a select on  B or A

```
entityA.Include(p => p.Cs.Select(pr => pr.EntityA))
```

or

```
entityB.Include(p => p.Cs.Select(pr => pr.EntityB))
```

Comment: I have another problem now  this ahs broken other parts of Dal where EntityA and EntityB have a one to one relastionship

Comment: Fixed  added A many to many mapping without the map with EntityA and Entity B Mapping.